# Alter Hive partition column name NOT changed in HDFS

Tags: hive, hdfs, partition, alter-table

When alter the partition column name of the partition table(named partitioned_table), the corresponding directory in the HDFS does not change. However, the deletion and movement of partitions can be changed in the HDFS.And the the column name is changed using "show partitioin partitioned_table".

Hive version is 4.0.0-alpha-2.
Use the below statement to alter partiton column name.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name PARTITION 
(partition_column = partition_col_value, 
partition_column = partition_col_value)  
RENAME TO PARTITION (partition_column = partition_col_value, 
partition_column = partition_col_value);
```

Why and how to change the corresponding directory in HDFS when alter partition column name in Hive.

Answer (score 0):

When you alter a partition, it only affects the Hive Metastore, and will never affect data in HDFS. For that, you need to explicitly insert data into the Hive table at that partition, or issue an `hdfs mv` command, then `MSCK REPAIR` Hive query to fix the metadata

Comment: Thanks .Why drop partitioin,move partion from one patitioned table is ok?which changed in HDFS.

Comment: I think the answer depends if the table is external or not